# " PHP Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user ..." in Raspberry Pi (Stretch)

Tags: php, postgresql, raspbian, php-7, raspberry-pi3

So sorry to bother everyone, I'm new to **PostgreSQL**, but my project requires me to build an automation system that connects to a server running PostgreSQL server. Long story short, let's just say I am required to perform a **data insertion/manipulation** from a **Web Form** into the server via **PHP** `pg_connect()`. The Web Form is located locally in `/var/www/html/web_form.html` and calls to a PHP script that performs the data insertion,

```
    <form name="some_name" action="script.php" method="POST">
```

so the data insertion is done to a local server.

I'm using a **Raspberry Pi 3** to simulate the "server" (as so not to "disturb" the true running server during such an early development). The Raspberry Pi is running a **Raspbian Stretch** distro. Well, it was originally Jessie, but then I decided to involve the Stretch repo from

```
    deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

with a priority of `100`. It also has `postgresql-9.6.3` (from Stretch), `php7.0.19-1` (also from Stretch), and `apache2.4.25` (from official Raspbian). Please do note that the Stretch repo do replaces **A LOT** of Jessie's official stable packages, and also known to be **"not quite stable"** itself, so it might also be the source of the problem.

I can access the database in the server from **remote computers**, whether using direct `psql`, Python (`psycopg2`), or even the exact same Web Form via PHP (tried from remote computer), so it will mostly won't be because of **PDO problems** (I've checked `phpinfo()` , but **feel free** to give advice on this, since I **don't really understand PDO myself**). On local, I can access the database via `psql`, but not local access via PHP (`pg_connect`).

I've meddled with this problem for hours now in vain. Please help me.

Here's my Raspberry Pi's configurations:

1.
A snippet of the PHP code:

```
    $conn_str="host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_db_name user=my_user_name password=my_password";
    $db = pg_connect($conn_str);
    if(!$db){
        $errormessage=pg_last_error();
        echo "Error 0: " . $errormessage;
        exit();
    }
```

Please mind that this same code **has perfectly worked** on another computer. I've **succeeded** to perform data insertion when the Web Form is located in a remote computer accessing the said server, or when the Web Form is accessing the remote computer's own local PostgreSQL server, but not when it is done in this **particular** problem server. When running in browser, it only shows:

```
    Error 0:
```

the result when running in console:

```
PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "raspiserver"

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "raspiserver" in php shell code on line 1
```

I also have tried to change `host=localhost` to `host=127.0.0.1` or `host=0.0.0.0`. I'm sure that the error came from that block of code, since that block is already on the first lines in my PHP code, while the other error reporting codes I put, each has distinct `Error X:` number.

2.
The PostgreSQL configurations:

For the `pg_hba.conf` content :

```
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                peer

    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   my_db_name     my_user_name     127.0.0.1/32            md5
    local   all     all                                             md5
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    # local   replication     postgres                                peer
    #host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
    #host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5

    #host   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
    host    another_db_name      my_user_name             192.168.52.0/24         trust
    host    my_db_name     my_user_name             192.168.52.0/24         trust
```

I already tried to comment/uncomment LINE 7, or change both LINE 7 and 8 to either `md5` , `trust` , or `password` . I also have tried to remove `127.0.0.1/32` from LINE 7, or change it to `127.0.0.0/24` or `0.0.0.0/0` . And, yes, I did performed

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload
    sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

(even `sudo reboot`) for every change I've made.

For the `postgresql.conf` content :

I already set `listen_addresses = '*'` and `password_encryption = on` , with the rest remained unchanged.

3.
Firewall :

`sudo iptables -L -n` doesn't show any entries :

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
```

What is wrong with my configurations?
Are Stretch the cause?
Or is it because the implementation of PostgreSQL-9.6?

I've already googled here and there, but most of the solutions only advice to change the `pg_hba.conf` to `trust` , or assume that the `user` name is not exist.

I'm desperate, please help.

(Please do mind that **I don't know anything** regarding PHP, PostgreSQL, Apache, or server, so please don't expect that I really know what I've done so far. **Please do analyze everything**.... Also, English is not my native, so I might mixed around some "jargons" here and there (if any).... Sorry for that... )

Answer (score 1):

This particular declaration in `pg_hba.conf` is incorrect:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   my_db_name     my_user_name     127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

because when the `TYPE` field is `local`, the line must have 4 fields, not 5: there is no `ADDRESS` field because it doesn't apply to Unix domain sockets (which is what `local` really means), only to TCP connections (which are declared with `TYPE` being `host` or `hostssl`)

When you reload PostgreSQL with a pg_hba.conf with this line, it will fail with

```
LOG:  invalid authentication method "127.0.0.1/32"
```

but you will see that only if looking in the server log. As a result of the failure, it will ignore your new version of `pg_hba.conf`.

Anyway this other line already in your file

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

probably does what you want. In this case just remove the offending line, reload again, and check the server log for a message indicating the success of the reload.

Comment: Okay, I will try to remove the <code>ADDRESS</code> field from LINE 7 next Monday. Out of curiosity, doesn't <code>host</code> means to enable remote access? Because my intention is to enable local access. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `host` itself does not enable that because it's interpred in conjunction (AND) with the `ADDRESS` mask. When `ADRESS` is `127.0.0.1/32` it says that the rule on this line applies only for connections that come from that address. But keep in mind that it's the entire set of rules that say what goes through and what is rejected, not just one line, and even less one column of one line. `pg_hba.conf` is interpreted on the whole as a big IF...ELSIF...ELSIF...ENDIF

Comment: I have tried to remove `ADDRESS` from LINE 7, the script is still not working. I also have tried to comment out the entire LINE 7 to no avail.

Comment: [A rewrite on previous reply, because who can wait for 5 minutes anyway!?] Sorry for long reply. I have tried to remove `ADDRESS` from LINE 7, the script is still not working. I also have tried to comment out the entire LINE 7 to no avail. I will try to read the server log (as you have stated above) for any failure to try to debug. If that still does not work, I will try to revert to Postgresql-9.4 and/or PHP 5. Will report back the soonest as possible. In the mean while, please feel free to give any further advice/directions, I will also try them alongside.

Comment: My boss just said, "If you could access the database from a Web Form in another remote computers, then just do so, instead of forcing it to work on the  Raspberry 'server'", so I will do so in the meanwhile.

But for the sake of research, I will keep digging into this problem until a clear solution surfaces. Still, I will need to prioritize my project first before this, but I will do this side quest alongside during a more leisure time and report my findings back.

Thank you for your help so far, Daniel.

Comment: Unrelated but, should I put a **tag** or something to this question? It is still **not really solved**, but my problems is no longer existing.